# how can i support <video> in Safari Browser?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i want to display a video in safari browser, when i refresh my browser, nothing happen, what should i do?

here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Simple Movie Player</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <video src="http://example.com/path/mymovie.mov"
             controls
             autoplay
             height="270" width="480">
      </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

can you help me please? Thank you...

Comment: does above code work in other browsers, chrome firefox?

Comment: yes, but only in safari is my problem.

Comment: <video controls>
    <source src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/video/boracaybeachvolleyballvideo.mp4'; ?>" type="video/mp4">
   </video> i try this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html) forum has the best answer for your question.

Though if you are looking for more robust solutions, go for [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) or [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using HTML5, then it is possible to use the video tag to play a video, however it is not possible to play any format with the default HTML5 player.
.MOV is not officially supported, but might still work in your browser, but if you wan't your video to be any of the official supported extension then convert it to .MP4, .OGG, WebM.

In HTML5 video tag on safari it officially supports .MP4 only.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 1):

`<video loop autoplay controls="true" src='http://example.com/path/mymovie.mov' type='video/mp4' width='100%' height='100%'></video>`

hope this helps